# Check table exist in AuthServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, service-provider

Hi is there a simplest and best way to check if a table exist inside a service provider?

Here's a scenario inside a service provider let say inside the AuthServiceProvider in this class under the boot function there are table record retrieval being done. But the question now is what if that table does not exist? then that line of code will fail right?

So upon running `php artisan migrate` somehow the code in the service provider is being executed (which I think should not be the case). So when I try to migrate this throws an error and the migrate command will fail since the table does not exist yet. To make it more clearer below is the possible scenario

// MyServiceProvider

```
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

        $my_table_record = MyTable::with('connectTable')->get(); <<-- this throws an error when running php artisan migrate since MyTable does not exist yet
    }
}
```

I can fix this by checking if the table already exist by adding a Schema import like below

```
// MyServiceProvider


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('my_table')) {
            $my_table_record = MyTable::with('connectTable')->get();
        }
    }
}
```

The second code fix the issue but I'm looking for a more elegant approach. Any idea on this? Would appreciate any suggestion

Comment: The 2nd approach is totally fine. What more elegance would you want?

Comment: It's just that I have this notion that Schema Facades should only be used in the Migration scripts (not that its really a standard) I just want that this facade be used only on the migration and not in the ServiceProvider

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the Schema Facade here and in fact I've done so many a time to ensure that I can boot the application when migrating without breaking it.

Comment: Your service providers will always run before a migration. Artisan will always load your app first and then run the command `migrate`.

Comment: @MikeHarrison that make sense. Probably I need to find a more elegant way to do this since it doesn't make sense that within my service provider I'm using a model call to retrieve a record but what if that model is not yet migrated and need to be migrated by php artisan migrate command. Meaning that code will not work. Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that make sense. Well probably I'll stick to that for the moment. Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: Why would the migration not have been ran yet? If you are creating new builds then you should just add the migrate command to the build process. That way even if there's nothing to be ran you know at least all migrations are up to date. This shouldn't really be a big concern unless you are git cloning or something without also migrating?

Comment: The scenario is I clone the project and this is done by other dev. Upon setting up my local dev environment (via vagrant) I run the php artisan migrate to have the tables initialized. But upon running I'm encountering an error saying the table doesn't exist yet. Upon checking the code the service provider has a code that retrieved data from a table (which is not yet created since migrate command failed). So the only solution was to comment out that line of code and do a migration command again then when the table is created I have to uncomment that code again